# Integer arithmetic overflow prevention in C

Tags: c, math, type-conversion, integer-overflow, integer-promotion

I thought the following code might cause an overflow since `a * 65535` is larger than what `unsigned short int` can hold, but the result seems to be correct.

Is there some built-in mechanism in C that stores intermediary arithmetic results in a larger data type? Or is it working as an accident?

```
unsigned char a = 30;
unsigned short int b = a * 65535 /100;
printf("%hu", b);
```

Comment: what bit width is `short int` on your compiler? compiler usually use its native bitwidth for constant expresion evaluations so its most likely computed on 32 or 64 bits and the result is then truncated to target bitwidth... the same applies to float/double unless you explicitly cats type (`1ull`, ...  `1.0, 1.0f`,... )

Answer (score 2):

It works because all types narrower than `int` will go under [default promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). Since `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` are both smaller than int on your platform, they'll be promoted to `int` and the result won't overflow if `int` contains <s>`CHAR_BIT + 17` bits or more (which is the result of `a * 65535` plus sign)</s> 22 bits or more (which is the number of bits in `30 * 65535` plus sign). However if `int` has fewer bits then overflow will occur and undefined behavior happens. It won't work if `sizeof(unsigned short) == sizeof(int)` either

Default promotion allows operations to be done faster (because most CPUs work best with values in its native size) and also prevents some naive overflow from happening. See

- [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/995714)
- [Will char and short be promoted to int before being demoted in assignment expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33337979/995714)
- [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/995714)